# GoJS TreeLayout different level for every child

Tags: javascript, treeview, gojs

I want to display a graph which depicts a timed process. Therefore, it would be desireable to have nodes aligned according to a given timeline.

The time stamps are totally accurate, which is why I chose them to be the keys of my groups. If two nodes have the same time stamp, they get added to the same group.

These groups are aligned by the TreeLayout. Per default they are aligned in the following way:

[image: not desired]

(Please note that the black boxes depict the groups and their alignment. The red boxes were added for better understanding on which level which group is.

What I would like to have, is a more timelined view of the diagram like so:

[image: Desired Output]

I tried setting `layerStyle: go.TreeLayout.LayerUniform`, and afterwards setting the `TreeVertex.level` accordingly, but GoJS didn't change its positioning.

Are there any other possibilities to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you assign TreeVertex.level in an override of TreeLayout.assignTreeVertexValues?

You might be interested in the LayeredTreeLayout example classes that are in two different samples: http://gojs.net/temp/swimBands2.html (no Groups) and http://gojs.net/temp/swimBands3.html (with Groups).

I hope the LayeredTreeLayout code in those files isn't too confusing.  They are slightly different from each other, due to the absence or presence of Groups, and the corresponding changes in the node data.